# Where does bitcoin-qt store it's initial settings

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup

I installed bitcoin-qt (v 0.12.1) on Kubuntu 15.10. When starting it the first time the GUI asked me for the datadir. I set it to an external disk.

Where are this settings stored? There is no `bitcoin.conf` file in my `/home/<user>/.bitcoin/` directory.

I know, that I can manually create the `bitcoin.conf` file. But I'm just curious, where the settings are stored, if no such file is present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcoin-Qt stores its own modifiable settings outside of `bitcoin.conf` (which is intended to only be read).

The location and format of that file is platform dependent, but on Linux it is `~/.config/Bitcoin/Bitcoin-Qt.conf`.